# Unable to resolve class LocalTime grails

Tags: grails, jodatime, gsp

I need realize a time input in my Grails application. I've downloaded joda-plugin for it. But when I want test it, writing a such string from doc example:
 `<joda:timePicker name="myTime" value="${new LocalTime()}" precision="second" />`, 
I get such error: `Unable to resolve class LocalTime` How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the class in your GSP to be able to use it.

Add

```
<%@ page import="org.joda.time.LocalTime" %>
```

at the top of your page.

Alternatively, use a fully qualified class reference in your `<joda:timePicker>` tag.